# Why is my loss trending down while my accuracy is going to zero?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, structured-data

I am trying to practice my machine learning skills with Tensorflow/Keras but I am having trouble around fitting the model. Let me explain what I've done and where I'm at.

I am using the dataset from Kaggle's [Costa Rican Household Poverty Level Prediction Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/costa-rican-household-poverty-prediction/data)

Since I am just trying to get familiar with the Tensorflow workflow, I cleaned the dataset by removing a few columns that had a lot of missing data and then filled in the other columns with their mean. So there are no missing values in my dataset.

Next I loaded the new, cleaned, csv in using `make_csv_dataset` from TF.

```
batch_size = 32

train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'clean_train.csv',
    batch_size,
    column_names=column_names,
    label_name=label_name,
    num_epochs=1)
```

I set up a function to return my compiled model like so:

```
f1_macro = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=4, average='macro')

def get_compiled_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(137,)),  # input shape required
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=[f1_macro, 'accuracy'])
    return model
```

```
model = get_compiled_model()
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=15)
```

Below is the result of that

[image: This is my output]

A link to my notebook is [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TPpjlmZjMoFIij3XjxLZ3iu50MY1MJl_)

I should mention that I strongly based my implementation on Tensorflow's iris data [walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough)

Thank you!

Comment: I tried changing `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy ` and it gave slightly more realistic accuracy but the loss numbers were huge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a while, I was able to find the issues with your code they are in the order of importance. (First is of highest importance)

1. You are doing multi-class classification (not binary classification). Therefore your loss should be `categorical_crossentropy`.
2. You are not onehot encoding your labels. Using `binary_crossentropy` and having labels as a numerical ID is definitely not the way forward. Instead, you should do onehot encode your labels and solve this like a multi-class classification problem. Here's how you do that.

```
def pack_features_vector(features, labels):
    """Pack the features into a single array."""
    features = tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=1)
    return features, tf.one_hot(tf.cast(labels-1, tf.int32), depth=4)
```

3. Normalizing your data. If you look at your training data. They are not normalized. And their values are all over the place. Therefore, you should consider normalizing your data by doing something like below. This is just for demonstration purposes. You should read about [Scalers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) in scikit learn and choose what's best for you.

```
x = train_df[feature_names].values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
train_df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
```

These issues should set your model straight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 1-2 were straightforward and easy to implement. Only issue is that the `pack_features_vector` label output gave me some problems because it would only predict classes [0,1,2,3] instead of [1,2,3,4] no biggie though.

One question I did have though was, would you normalize the whole data set or just columns with large ranges, say 1-100,000?